# an algebra question about hermitian and unitary

Tags: linear-algebra

If $H_1$ and $H_2$ are two semi-positive definite hermitian matrices, $U_1$ and $U_2$ are two unitary matrices, $A$ is a square matrix, then if $H_1AH_2=U_1AU_2$, is it true that $H_1AH_2=A$?

Comment: Can $U_1,U_2$ be unitary *and* Hermitian?

Comment: Yes, they can be both unitary and Hermitian in general(but since $H_1,H_2$ are semi-positive, they will not be unitary except for identity). if this whole statement is true  is my wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not.  Choosing
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
0 &\dots &0\\
\vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \dots & 0
}
$$
Means that this equality holds regardless of the other choices of matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have changed my question so that it will not be that confusing.